# Bootstrap Accordion and Ajax (on Flask)

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, flask

All,

I'm trying to populate a boostrap accordion expanded div with html using ajax- namely, only load the html if a user expands a collapsed accordion element. The HTML is:

```
<script src="/static/expand_db.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body ">This is the panel's body</div>

                    <div id="collapse0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">expanded content - this is to be loaded with ajax</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <a id="expand0" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0">Expand</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the associated javascript (straight from the flask docs) is:

```
  $(function() {
  $('a#expand0').on('show.bs.collapse', function (){
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
        a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
        b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Now (clearly), the code won't work (no var's a and b, '#results' div not defined, which is left as a followup/edit for later), but monitoring the console (using Eclipse, flask requests are shown there), there seems to be no server call at all when pressing the 'expand' link. Note that the accordion works fine (expands and collapses).

Replacing 
`$('a#expand0').on('show.bs.collapse', function (){` with 
`$('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {` in the javascript shows the proper server call: "**127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2014 11:45:58] "GET /_add_numbers HTTP/1.1" 404 -**"

but overrides the accordion expand functionality (which makes sense).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you swap use the `click` binding, returning `false` at the end of the function will override the collapse function.  Removing the `return false;` may help.

As to doing it using the `show.bs.collapse` binding, is it really the `a#expand0` element that has a `show.bs.collapse` event?  Isn't it the `#collapse0` element (or one of the others)?